# Writing custom class to do the same as .container-fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The project I am working has css file where .container-fluid is overwritten on in a file imported by in all Vue project.

I am adding 7 pages to these pages. And the overwritten behavior is useful for old 20 pages.

But I need to use .container-fluid in other pages and if I use it it won't work as I want.

How to solve this issue?
Can I write css class to do the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Keep in mind that Bootstrap is merely a framework for you to build on top of, and essentially just creates a list of 'base' CSS rules for you to either overwrite or make use of. If you want Bootstrap's `container-fluid` to apply to some pages and not others, simply create a custom CSS class and make use of that on the other pages:

```
.container-custom {
  width: 50%;
}

<div class="container-custom">
```

And for your pages that you want to use the Bootstrap container for:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Note that the `.container-custom` rule won't apply to the `class="container-fluid"` element(s), so they will still have the Bootstrap styling.

Also, don't forget there is also the standard **[`.container`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#containers)** in Bootstrap, which you may find useful.